# Not able to use hosts file in browser

Tags: iis, hosts

I have a site setup in IIS, as a default site. I'm able to browse it using `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1`. Also, I'm able to access it using `telnet localhost 80`.

I have an alias set in the `hosts` file like

```
127.0.0.1 simple-site
```

If i use `ping simple-site` I get a correct ping response.

However, if I try `http://simple-site` or `telnet simple-site 80` I'm not able to access it.

This happens whether I add a host-header binding with `simple-site` to the default site or not.

The firewall is completely turned off, and a similar setup works perfectly on another machine. Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: What does your site binding setting in IIS look like?

Comment: It's completely empty now, but I get exactly same results if I add `simple-site` as a host header binding.

Comment: What happens if you add the site as a separate entry rather than amending the default entry?

Comment: It was not working because the loopback IP address was not operational. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - basically I have an error in the question, `http://127.0.0.1` was not actually working. 
The problem was that the 127.0.0.1 address was not enabled via `netsh` (I have no idea why)

After we added it using

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```

both `http://127.0.0.1` and `http://simple-site` became operational. I have no idea how or why it was not enabled, and obviously there's something that does not use the IP's when we use `localhost`.